# How do I get filtered Subclasses from sealed Class

Tags: kotlin

I have Sealed Class like below.

```
sealed class Number {

    object One: Number() {
    }
    
    object Two: Number() {
    }
    
    object Three: Number() {
    }
    
    object Four: Number() {
    }
}
```

then, I want to use `One`, and `Two` using `sealedSubclasses`.

```
    // this code compile error. `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'KClass<out KClass<out Number>>' and 'Number.One'`
    val subClasses = Number::class.sealedSubclasses.filter { clazz -> clazz::class == Number.One }
```

Can I solve this? Do you know any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `clazz == Number.One::class`.

Currently, you’re using `clazz::class` which is `KClass<out KClass<out Number>>`, the class of what was already a class.

And you forgot the `::class` at the end.

However, you’re filtering to find out which subclass is the class you already know so there’s no point. You could just replace you’re whole line of code with `val subclasses = listOf(Number.One::class)`.